# What does the this code in socket.io mean

Tags: php, node.js, sockets

I am new to real-time programming using socket.io and node.js. I have seen this code from a blog site unfortunately did not post any comment or explanation about the code below:

```
socket.on( 'new_message', function( data ) {
  io.sockets.emit( 'new_message', {
    name: data.name, 
    address : data.address
 });
});
```

I have checked the socket.io documentation but there are no sufficient explanations in connection with PHP server using XAMMP.

I am using a PHP as my server-side scripting language and the code above communicates with the PHP script, but, I don't know the meaning of those codes.

after socket.on, there is a name 'new_message'. I don't know how it worked.

Also, there are JSON name: data.name , emit function,.. I don't know where did these

exist.Somebody will try to explain what's going on here?

Comment: Why are you using nodejs AND php?

Comment: I am using PHP to save data into the database. Now, for nodejs, it runs the socket.io to send and retrieve data into the database via real time.,

Comment: Personally, I don't think this is right place to ask this question, because essentially the code works. From what I understand about it (not experienced with Node.JS), it does the following: When the socket receives a new message, it emits (sends) the message to all connected clients, containing the senders (the one that send the message to the socket) name and most likely IP address

Comment: If you prefer php as your back-end take a look at php socket.io servers: https://github.com/walkor/phpsocket.io. Check out the link. To answer some of your question, `socket.on( 'new_message' ...` in the browser means that the client is waiting for the `new_mesage` packet from the server. If you use php server in the link I posted above it means it is waiting for the server to do `$io->emit('new_message', ...`.

Comment: Do you mean that, if I use PHP, there's no need for me to have a node.js? sorry, I am new to node

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
socket.on( 'new_message', function )
```

When the server [receives an event (or message)](https://socket.io/docs/server-api/#socket-on-eventname-callback) named `new_message` from this socket connection,

```
io.sockets.emit( 'new_message', data )
```

the server will re [emit](https://socket.io/docs/server-api/#namespace-emit-eventname-args) that message out to all sockets connected to the [default namespace](https://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/#default-namespace).

```
{
    name: data.name, 
    address : data.address
}
```

The data will contain the same `name` and `address` from the original incoming event.

This new message will also go back to the socket that created it, in case that matters.

The [socket.io API docs](https://socket.io/docs/server-api/) aren't the easiest to read but they do cover most of the API. The [socket.io](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io) and [engine.io](https://github.com/socketio/engine.io) git repos cover the rest.